# Not getting videos from youtube api

Tags: php, youtube-api

I am new to android and php and working on old project.

Everything worked smoothly till yesterday. I am getting all videos from you tube api:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=&start-index=1&max-results=10&v=2&alt=json
```

But from today, i just get only one video from this link and that is:

```
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6098135?p=yt_devicesupport&hl=en&rd=1
```

I have read that v2 become depreciated so i need to move to v3 version ?
I need help on how to get all videos as before.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really an easy answer for this.  At least, we can't really just give you a new address to plop in the place of the old one.  API v3 is structured differently and has different requirements than v2.  Some of those changes at least theoretically bring some performance advantages, but when requesting things from this new API, you need to be more specific about what you're looking for.  Also, since some of the data has moved around within the JSON results, you may need to change where your code looks for given information.

As it is, I don't really know what information you need, or for that matter, what collection of videos you're looking for.  In this version of the API, these details actually matter.  In v3, you have to provide a comma-separated list of the information you're looking for, and then at least one more "filter" parameter as well (filters, for your cases are probably either "chart" which is something like the "chart of the most popular", or "id" which is a comma-separated list of video IDs.)

While it's probably not the answer you were looking for, you probably need to stroll through the documentation.  I especially suggest [the Try It section](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it), where you can plug in your parameters and build the query.

You'll need an API key to use the new API, and you can get that key from [the Google Developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/). Create a new project, and add the YouTube API to it.